# A very simple cipher

Tags: cipher

I was looking at some of my old notes and documents, and I found an old cipher I made.

Here it is:

> Dreary photograph opinion house subway bottom underworld vehicle mamba beautiful unexpected jolly potato onion tree

Edit: I would love to give some hints and things, but I don't remember my method for encoding it!

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! I highly recommend reading [Code Puzzles: What (not) to do?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do?noredirect=1&lq=1) over on our meta site.

Comment: Just to be clear: are you saying that, even though you created this puzzle, you don't know the answer?

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 9):

> The first letters of the words spell out "Congratulations" when shifted one letter backwards.